# How can i transfer files from Google Cloud Instance to AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, gcloud, file-transfer

How can I transfer files from google cloud instance to AWS instance, live transfer solution will be perfect if there is an option like this?

Thanks.

Comment: The question, as stated, is too vague. Are you trying to maintain two VMs in sync? Are you transferring simple files like a set of images, or are you trying to transfer an installed application, or the entire OS, for example?

Comment: The best solution will be to sync the VM from google cloud to aws instance but if there is no option like this so I want at least copy all the files from all the disks to an instance in aws.

Comment: You might be able to capture an image of the GCE instance, then export it as VMDK or VHDX using "gcloud compute images export", then import it into AWS using VM Import. I have not tried this. Personally, I'd rather simply launch a new, compatible OS on AWS, reinstall the necessary apps, and then import the data via S3 (or scp/rsync).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to copy files on a one-off basis, you can use the scp commend to copy the files.

```
scp -i awskey.pub sourceFile user@host:directory/targetFile
```

To do this, you will need to have a copy of your public ssh key to AWS and pass this to scp with the -i parameter.